# why can we tackle a matrix with linearly dependent rows while driving artificial variables out of the basis?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex

in [introduction to linear programming](https://personal.vu.nl/l.stougie/Courses/ALP/BTonlyCh12345.pdf), section 3.5 driving artificial variables out of the basis, the authors consider the case where that when trying to drive the lth basic variable (which is artificial), we find out that the lth row of $B^{-1}A$ is zero, which means that A has linearly dependent rows (last paragraph of page 113)

How is that possible? I thought that our assumption is that A has full rank! and that we test for that before the optimization...

Thanks!

related to [why in Phase I of the simplex method, if artificial variable become nonbasic, it never become basic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403053/why-in-phase-i-of-the-simplex-method-if-artificial-variable-become-nonbasic-it)

Comment: Please specify where you´ve read that the lth row is $0$.

Comment: @callculus - edited